# What value in Python equals everything?

Tags: python

Is there a value in Python that, when compared using `==` to *any* other value, always returns `True`? I suspect this wouldn't make sense, because if you compare this said value to `False` it probably shouldn't return `True`. But I'm curious to see if it does exist!

Comment: You can create one by overwriting the [related magic methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could certainly create one:

```
class Anything:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True
```

Obviously there's a question of which one wins if both sides of a comparison implement `__eq__`; it's the one on the left of the `==`, so `Anything() == x` is true for all `x`, but not necessarily the other way around.